# Show related Taxonomy list if created

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have created the following construction. If a student choose option A with the if construction the following step in the wizard is the internships with medicine domain A, but what if the school create another medicine domain B. With this construction the student will only see the internship domain A and not the medicine domain a AND b. I'm looking for a construction that grows with my Taxonomy (shows medicine domain a and b and if the school create 5 months later a medicine domain c that last one must seen by the student also), so if a student choose medicine than he get all medicine domains (medicine domain a and b and so on) and not just $internship domain a as defined in my if structure. Hope you understand my problem because it is explained in terrible English.

enter code here 
case 2:

```
// Taxonomy list: 'valid type of internship'.

$valueInternship = $_SESSION['gekozenOpleiding'];

//var_dump($valueInternship);

if($valueInternship == 1) { // Stagedomein a
    $internship = 10;
}

if($valueInternship == 2) { // Stagedomein b
    $internship = 11;
}

if($valueInternship == 3) { // Stagedomein c
    $internship = 13;
}

if($valueInternship == 4) { // Stagedomein d
    $internship = 12;
}

if($valueInternship == 5) { // Stagedomein e
    $internship = 14;
}

$dropdown_source_geldig_soort_stage = taxonomy_get_tree($internship);
$dropdown_array_geldig_soort_stage = array();
foreach ($dropdown_source_geldig_soort_stage as $item) {
    $key = $item->tid;
    $value = $item->name;
    $dropdown_array_geldig_soort_stage[$key] = $value;
}
$form['geldig_soort_stage'] = array(
        '#key_type' => 'associative',
        '#multiple_toggle' => '1',
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#options' => $dropdown_array_geldig_soort_stage,
        '#title' => 'Welk geldig soort stage',
        '#multicolumn' => array('width' => 4,
                '#default_value' => isset($default_value['geldig_soort_stage']) ?
                $default_value['geldig_soort_stage'] : '',
        ),
);
break;
```

Comment: perhaps a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish as output would be helpful.

Comment: we can't help you if we don't understand the question...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very frequent problem. Drupal has a simple solution. It is called the [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context).

The context module will allow you to ONLY show information based on term throughout the whole website. Or, only show information based on a user role. So a teacher will have different Views show in a block than a student who will have different Views based on the internship they have.

The context module also allows you to stack. You can have a context for A, B, C, D. In the Right block region of the page.tpl.php that shows four different blocks based on the taxonomy terms selected. If the student selects term A & B. Then they have the Views block for a & b show at the same time. Or, they can have terms A, B & C. If term A shows 1 block and term B shows 1 block then A & B will have two sidebar blocks showing. If intership C is much more complicated and requires 5 blocks of information then a student with terms A, B & C will have 7 blocks on one page.